# In R: how to access the index in library(help = "pcks_name")?

Tags: r, package

I would like to access the list of functions and their descriptions that is given in
`library(help = "pcks_name")`

My ideal would be to have this list exported into a file (txt, html, pdf).

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at how the `helpr` package access this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
res <- library(help="MASS")
class(res) <- "list"
```

and access `res$info[[2]]`

Comment: Nice Karsten, thanks.  mmm... I wonder how to "know" that there are several sets of functions (data, functions, etc.).  Is this a convention? since I don't remember seeing this distinction in the help of other packages...

Comment: Looking at the library function with `page(library)` it seems that library(help) looks at the DESCRIPTION file, at package.rds, at INDEX, and at vignette.rds. May be this is where these sets come from?